# Regex for URL's that don't appear in quotes? (javascript)

Tags: javascript, jquery, regex, web

Currently I have a regular expression that will find all URL's within a block of html.  It looks like this:

```
elementHTML.match(/(http|ftp|https):\/\/[\w-]+(\.[\w-]+)+([\w.,@?^=%&amp;:\/~+#-]*[\w@?^=%&amp;\/~+#-])?/ig);
```

When a URL is detected it is replaced with something that looks like:

```
<div data="URL_THAT_WAS_DETECTED">Information about that url</div>
```

The data attribute is custom added.

How can I continue to look for URL's without picking up the previously detected URL?

Ideally, I would like either ignore URL's that are in quotes or possibly html tags but I'm open to suggestions.

Any help is greatly appreciated, Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This regex will do it:

```
 /(http|ftp|https):\/\/[\w-]+(\.[\w-]+)+(?![^\s]*?")([\w.,@?^=%&amp;:\/~+#-]*[\w@?^=%&amp;\/~+#-])?/ig
```

I've added a negative lookahead for double quotes `"` characters.

[**Live Demo**](http://regexr.com?3157i)

Comment: Awesome! Just tried it out and it works perfectly! You the man